# Dynamics CRM 4 Delete Plugin not running

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I Have a plugin that should run on delete of a custom entity that wont run.

Plugin is registered with Plugin Registrtion Tool setting:

- Message - Delete
- Primary Entity - myCustomEntity
- Secondary Entity - none
- Filetering Attributes - All Attributes
- Plugin - the one i want to run
- Run in user Context - calling user
- Execurion Order - 1
- Pre Stage
- Synchronous
- Step Deployment - Server
- Trigeting Pipeline - Parent

with an image called Target  registerd as a pre-image.

there are no errors logged on the server and debuging in visual studio with a breakpoint on the first statements in the constructor and execute methods does not result in it entering debug.

any idea what i have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out, i had this line

```
if (context.InputParameters.Properties.Contains(ParameterName.EntityMoniker) &&
           context.InputParameters.Properties[ParameterName.EntityMoniker] is Moniker)
```

which is how it works for MessageName.SetStateDynamicEntity, changed to

```
if (context.InputParameters.Properties.Contains(ParameterName.Target) &&
           context.InputParameters.Properties[ParameterName.Target] is Moniker)
```

and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're ever unclear on what parameters you might expect in the `InputParameters` PropertyBag for a given message, you can look at the SDK for the appropriate *MessageNameRequest* class and see the Instance Properties for that object (e.g. the `DeleteRequest` class has just a `Target` property (of type `TargetDelete`).